# Decide what is the number of roots of the equation

Tags: analysis

> Decide what is the number of roots of the equation $2^x=100x$.

I know I can draw a sketch and then check but maybe there is a better method to do that? It's an exam question, thus it must require a bit more sophisticated method.

Comment: Study the function $f(x)=2^x-100x$, and find the monotonous sections (using the derivative). There is a root in all monotonous section with a change of sign, and only there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The graphs of a convex function and a line cannot meet in more than two points. If we take $f(x)=2^x$, the only solution of $f'(x)=100$ is given by $x=\frac{\log(100)-\log(\log 2)}{\log(2)}$, and in such a point $f(x)$ equals $\frac{100}{\log 2}$. It follows that $2^x=100 x$ has two real solutions, the first one close to $0$, the second one close to $10$.

Comment: And by plugging $x=0$, $x=5$ and $x=10$ (and the limits for $x\to -\infty$, $x\to +\infty$) into $f$ and into $g(x):=100x$ (which is very easy to do without electronic aid) we see that the solution which is close to $0$, is positive, and the solution which is close to $10$, is a less than $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function and its derivatives $$f(x)=2^x-k x$$ $$f'(x)=2^x \log (2)-k$$ $$f''(x)=2^x \log ^2(2)$$ The first derivative cancels at $$x_*=\frac{\log \left(\frac{k}{\log (2)}\right)}{\log (2)}$$ and $$f(x_*)=\frac{k}{\log (2)}-\frac{k }{\log (2)}\log \left(\frac{k}{\log (2)}\right)$$ which is always negative if $k\gt e\log(2)$. The second derivative test show that, in such a case, this is a minimum.

So, two roots if $k\gt e\log(2)$.